# C# TypeConverter.ConvertFrom() problem

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion, typeconverter

I have a problem with the following code which returns an object from a string:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(MyConverter))]
public class MyClass
{
    public string s;
}

public class MyConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        return (sourceType == typeof(string)) ? true : base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if (value is string)
        {
            MyClass m = new MyClass();
            m.s = (string)value;
            return m;
        }

        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }
}
```

When I try to use with this code:

```
string s_test = "test";

MyClass m_test;

m_test = (MyClass)Convert.ChangeType(s_test, typeof(MyClass));
```

I get the error message

> Invalid cast from 'System.String' to
>   'MyClass'.

What is wrong in my code? 
Note that I must use the ConvertFrom() method...

Thank you in advance for your help.

Stack trace:

```
[InvalidCastException: Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'MyClass'.]
   System.Convert.DefaultToType(IConvertible value, Type targetType, IFormatProvider provider) +9496632
   System.String.System.IConvertible.ToType(Type type, IFormatProvider provider) +8
   System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider) +9531720
   System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType) +32
   OrderController.Index() in [...].cs:70
   ... omitted for brevity ...
```

Answer (score 8):

You're expecting `Convert.ChangeType` to use a `TypeConverter` if one is present - it doesn't. `TypeConverter` is usually used in conjunction with `TypeDescriptor` (often implicitly in UI frameworks).

Comment: Yes you are right, my problem comes from Telerik ASP MVC Grid control... See my latest comment

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be under the impression that `Convert.ChangeType` looks for a `TypeConverter`.  It doesn't.

From [the MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08.aspx): "For the conversion to succeed, value must implement the IConvertible interface"

Since `System.String` doesn't implement `IConverter<MyClass>`, you're out of luck (with the `Convert` class, anyway).  Like Skeet said [(and MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.aspx), use `TypeDescriptor` instead.

Comment: Ok thank your for your answers.
In fact I would like to use the DisplayTemplate in a Telerik Grid MVC http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-display-and-editor-templates.html and I get the same error message Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'MyClass' so I try to understand what Telerik does and what fails...

Does anyone has an idea??

Answer (score 3):

Building off of the correct answer from Jon Skeet, you need to use the `TypeDescriptor` to do the conversion. Change your test code from:

```
string s_test = "test";
MyClass m_test;
m_test = (MyClass)Convert.ChangeType(s_test, typeof(MyClass));
```

To:

```
string s_test = "test";
MyClass m_test;
m_test = (MyClass)TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(MyClass)).ConvertFromString(test);
```

and all should be well.

Answer (score 2):

(Found this link while searching for the answer to a similar question, so posting the best answer I found)

The *implicit* and *explicit* operators seem to be what you want, TypeConverter isn't needed

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string s;

    public static explicit operator MyClass(string s) {
        MyClass m = new MyClass();
        m.s = (string)value;
        return m;
    }
}
```

Which allows the following:-

```
string s_test = "test";

MyClass m_test;

m_test = (MyClass)s_test;
```

Note: The above is untested, but should be close enough to give the needed clues.

Answer (score 0):

The [SixPack library](http://code.google.com/p/sixpack-library/) has a [TypeConverter](http://code.google.com/p/sixpack-library/source/browse/trunk/src/SixPack/ComponentModel/TypeConverter.cs) class that supports most of the .NET conversion methods, including TypeConverter. The conversions that are supported are the following:

- TypeConverter on source type
- TypeConverter on destination type
- C# explicit and implicit casting operators
- IConvertible

There is also special treatment of the following types

- DbNull
- Nullable
- Enum
- TimeSpan